# Do I need a transit visa to visit Istanbul on my layover? Do airlines offer any city tours?

Tags: transit-visas, turkey, uk-residents, bangladeshi-citizens

I have a Bangladeshi passport but is currently living in UK with a student visa. Can I enter Turkey at my transit without a Turkish  visa? I will be travelling with Turkish Airlines and have a layover at Ataturk Airport. 
I also read somewhere that Turkish Airline offers city tours in long transits. Is that true?

Answer (score 2):

As [stated](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa) in the website of *Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Turkey*, ordinary Bangladeshi nationals are required to have a visa to enter Turkey. However, since you have a UK residence permit, you are eligible to apply for a single entry e-Visa which is valid for one month.

Turkish Airlines, does offer guided tours in Istanbul for layovers of at least 6 hours. You can find more details on [How To Apply](http://www.istanbulinhours.com/how-to-apply) on their website.

Comment: Good answer. One small note for brevity. Min 6 hours and Max 24 hours. And no application required, just clear immigration and go to Hotels Desk next to Starbucks. That's it. Even the meal on the tour is free. You only have to pay for anything you might want to buy from shops on the tour. If not, there are no costs other than the possible cost of eVisa

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=BD&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=TR&selDest=Turkey&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of normal passports issued
>   to nationals of Bangladesh holding a visa valid on arrival,
>   issued by Ireland (Rep.), USA or **United Kingdom** or a Schengen
>   Member State can obtain a visa or an e-visa on
>   arrival, for a max. stay of 1 month. Fee: USD 30.-, EUR 25.-
>   or GBP 20.-. The e-visa can also be obtained online prior to
>   departure at www.evisa.gov.tr.

So you can either apply for an electronic entry Permit [HERE](http://www.evisa.gov.tr), or you can get it at a Kiosk at Istanbul Airport.

Comment: The only problem with getting it at the Kiosk at airport is that right next to you the passport control queue keeps growing and growing and growing and those 3 minutes seem like eternity

Comment: @HankyPanky Makes sense. The two times I flew into Atatürk I had to queue for 10-15 minutes despite being the first person to leave my all-but-empty plane (I don't need an e-visa)